# Make ASP.Net generate cleaner HTML source code?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

When I view the HTML source code for a page generated by razor markup it is displayed on a single line, this make it hard to dig through the source code to try and debug. Is there a way to make the razor output cleaner to read?

Razor Code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @class = "Form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(false)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ID)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.LogoFileID)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.BannerFileID)
}
```

Normal Output code:

```
<form action="/Admin/SectionData/EditSection" class="Form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="vtuiL8hTRJqtVcjPB-FJzL3e_4Tq3YnaH6kJVVBjzg5v4tlNt8_-Nb6H3tdRRv2SQXDsv4kJfZI-O2gmoAV_h4HcFaBArI4xSn4iFS0u0Cc1" /><div class="validation-summary-valid" data-valmsg-summary="true"><ul><li style="display:none"></li>
```

Output I would like:

```
<form action="/Admin/SectionData/EditSection" class="Form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="vtuiL8hTRJqtVcjPB-FJzL3e_4Tq3YnaH6kJVVBjzg5v4tlNt8_-Nb6H3tdRRv2SQXDsv4kJfZI-O2gmoAV_h4HcFaBArI4xSn4iFS0u0Cc1" />
    <div class="validation-summary-valid" data-valmsg-summary="true">
        <ul>
            <li style="display:none"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field ID must be a number." data-val-required="The ID field is required." id="ID" name="ID" type="hidden" value="110" />
    <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field LogoFileID must be a number." id="LogoFileID" name="LogoFileID" type="hidden" value="" />
    <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field BannerFileID must be a number." id="BannerFileID" name="BannerFileID" type="hidden" value="" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to make the razor output cleaner to read?

The expectation is other way round. In most cases user want engine to output minified (without whitespaces, line breaks, etc) html to save network bandwidth.

When you want to read the generated HTML and make out what it means, you can use an online HTML viewer like [Online HTML Viewer](http://codebeautify.org/htmlviewer/)

OR

You can find a browser extension e.g. for Chrome [Browser Extension](http://www.htmlkit.com/blog/html-tidy-browser-extension/)

Comment: I would not care about it being minified when in production but in dev it would be nice to be a lot cleaner without having to copy and paste it around.

Comment: I see your need. I haven't come across anything that make browser render html in a particular way. Its browser dependent. BTW no need to copy paste, i am sure an extension would automatically format the html.